# SQL question - find a number from a list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 100 numbers in it. Now i have a list of 11 numbers, one of them is not in the table (different for the 100 numbers from it).

When i query after my list of 11 numbers `select * from table where number in (' ',' ',' '......)` it returns the 10 numbers that are in the table.

Now my question is: how do i find the number from my list which is not in the table? (only with SQL, because right now i am using Excel to do that).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle database you can use **NOT IN** also..

means as you have used and aware about **IN** keyword, same way, for you desired output you can use NOT IN...

you can use following query also for this --

case 1 : that 10 number you have in a table - (say table name is list1)

```
select list1.num from list1
where list1.num not in (select distinct table.number from table)
```

case 2 : as you have posted your question looking like you don't have numbers in a table -

```
select list1.num from 
(
select number1 num from dual
union
select number2 num from dual
union
select number3 num from dual
union
select number4 num from dual
union
select number5 num from dual
union
select number6 num from dual
union
select number7 num from dual
union
select number8 num from dual
union
select number9 num from dual
union
select number10 num from dual
union
select number11 num from dual
) list1
where list1.num not in (select distinct table.number from table)
```

in place of number1 to number11 you have to paste your list number..

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the values clause:

```
with yourlist as (
select 1 as i from dual
union all
select 2 as i from dual
...
union all
select 3 as i from dual
)
select yourlist.i
from yourlist
left join yourtable
on yourtable.num = yourlist.i
where yourtable.num is null
```

Comment: @Denis: Thank you for you help. Unfortunately i am getting an error "invalid table name". And yes you are right, i don;t know how to create the table with cte :)

Comment: @Ion: I fixed the join clause in my above query (it had a slight error). which table name is it reporting as invalid? [Other sample query](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.1.3/devguide/cdevtricks807365.html).

Comment: @Denis: It doesn't say which one, but i am guessing that "numbers" because the other one is in my DB. It is only "ORA-00903: invalid table name" and pl/sql developer puts a red line under "v" from "values".

Comment: Check spelling/try changing it in case numbers is a reserved word. (I can only test it in Postgres, personally.)

Comment: @Tony: oh. I thought it would be considering [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.1.3/devguide/cdevtricks807365.html) (from oracle.com).

Comment: That link is talking about something called JavaDB from Apache, which I've not heard of before.  Interesting!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to put your list of numbers in a second table, then use a left join to find where it doesn't match

```
SELECT number FROM list
LEFT JOIN table USING(number)
WHERE table.number IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, but that is only half of what he wants. I think he's unaware of how to create that second table using a cte (see my answer). :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is functionally equivalent to @Denis' answer, but uses slightly different techniques:

```
CREATE TYPE nt_number AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

SELECT   COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   table(nt_number(1,3,8,12,14))
MINUS
SELECT   NUMBER_COLUMN
  FROM   YOUR_TABLE;
```

Changing `MINUS` to `INTERSECT` would give you the values that exist in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I missread your questin first :)

The numbers in a temporary table and joining against that is the best bet.

Comment: This is incorrect. It'll give *all* numbers that *aren't* in his list. He wants *the* number in his list that *isn't* in the table.

Comment: The edit is still based `SELECT * FROM table WHERE`.  The problem with that is that the number is *not* in the table (it's in the list that appears in your WHERE clauses).